# How can I access a port of a machine on a vlan from the internet?

Tags: hyper-v, port-forwarding, vlan, internet

I have a hyper-v guest instance that is configured to be on a VLAN (configured all via my Cisco RV325 router and which via vlan DHCP runs on a segregated network).

My question is : How can I access this hyper-v guest instance from the internet? I run a software license server on that hyper-v guest instance that needs to be accessed via the internet so that any of my machines that I use on the road can access that license server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the server uses the Cisco router as its gateway and can access the Internet, then the VLAN is fairly irrelevant. You just need to configure port forwarding on the Cisco and forward the correct port to the private IP address (assuming the DHCP server / VLAN network is using private addresses) of the server instance.

Comment: Got it, I just set it up exactly as you explained and it works. Thanks